# Python "print" does not log to Forever.js Logs

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, forever

A Python 2.7 script outputs some debug info via `print` as it runs.

```
....
print datetime.now()
...
```

This script is started by [forever.js](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever):

```
forever start -c python myPrintingScript.py
```

However when I want to check the output of the Python script, nothing shows up in the logs.

Running `forever logs 0` returns nothing. But the script definitely is running and has not crashed/restarted.

**Question:** Is there a way to get the Python script to print debug info such that it also appears in the log files of `forever`?

Answer (score 2):

Please do as this:

```
import sys
print "xxxx"
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Then you will see `xxxx` in the log file that forever created.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify output logs for forever

```
-l  LOGFILE      Logs the forever output to LOGFILE
-o  OUTFILE      Logs stdout from child script to OUTFILE
-e  ERRFILE      Logs stderr from child script to ERRFILE
```

For example:

```
forever -o out.log -e err.log myPrintingScript.py
```